# Injection of Java class and rebind to InitialContext

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jboss, module, wildfly

I try to rebind a java class called SomeProcess to the JNDI. This binding happens inside a singleton bean called ResourceBinder.

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
ctx.rebind("SomeProcess", new SomeProcess());
log.info(">>>>> SomeProcess bound");
```

Later, this class is injected inside other ejb called SomeServiceBean.

```
@Inject
private SomeProcess process;
```

However, I am getting this error:

> org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.NamingIOException: Failed to rebind
>   [Root exception is java.io.IOException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   de.brockhaus.userMgmt.control.process.SomeProcess from [Module
>   "org.jboss.remote-naming:main" from local module loader @ed17bee
>   (finder: local module finder @2a33fae0 (roots: C:\Program
>   Files\jboss\wildfly\modules,C:\Program
>   Files\jboss\wildfly\modules\system\layers\base))]]    at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:49)
>   2015-12-28 20:33:02,302 DEBUG [main]
>   de.brockhaus.userMgmt.util.jndi.BeanLocator: Looking up for:
>   /BRO130_3_7_ResourceBinder-solution/SomeServiceBean!de.brockhaus.userMgmt.boundary.SomeService
>     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$3.execute(Protocol.java:306)
>     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$3.execute(Protocol.java:265)
>     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1.rebind(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:116)
>     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore$3.operation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:302)
>     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore$3.operation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:299)
>     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingOperation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:137)
>     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.rebind(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:298)
>     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.rebind(RemoteContext.java:163)
>     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.rebind(RemoteContext.java:170)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:433)  at
>   de.brockhaus.userMgmt.boundary.ResourceBinder.bindResources(ResourceBinder.java:32)
>     at
>   de.brockhaus.userMgmt.boundary.SomeServiceTest.bindResources(SomeServiceTest.java:21)
>     at
>   de.brockhaus.userMgmt.boundary.SomeServiceTest.main(SomeServiceTest.java:13)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   de.brockhaus.userMgmt.control.process.SomeProcess from [Module
>   "org.jboss.remote-naming:main" from local module loader @ed17bee
>   (finder: local module finder @2a33fae0 (roots: C:\Program
>   Files\jboss\wildfly\modules,C:\Program
>   Files\jboss\wildfly\modules\system\layers\base))]     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$3.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:329)
>     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:73)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   de.brockhaus.userMgmt.control.process.SomeProcess from [Module
>   "org.jboss.remote-naming:main" from local module loader @ed17bee
>   (finder: local module finder @2a33fae0 (roots: C:\Program
>   Files\jboss\wildfly\modules,C:\Program
>   Files\jboss\wildfly\modules\system\layers\base))]     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)   at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.loadClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:131)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.resolveClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:112)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:948)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1255)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
>     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$3.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:327)
>     ... 4 more

In order to solve it, I have created a wilfly module de.brockhaus.userMgmt where I have put the maven build jar. This is the module.xml content

```
<properties>
    <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
</properties>

<resources>
    <resource-root path="BRO130_3_7_ResourceBinder-solution.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
</dependencies>
```

I have modified the `module.xml` of the module `org.jboss.remote-naming` in WildFly 10 release.

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.jboss.remote-naming">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jboss-remote-naming-2.0.4.Final.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.ejb-client" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.remoting"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.marshalling"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.marshalling.river"/>
        <module name="de.brockhaus.userMgmt"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

But now the problem is different: 13:36:01,016 ERROR

> [org.jboss.as.naming] (pool-1-thread-1) WFLYNAM0008: Unexpected
>   internal error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: WFLYNAM0043:
>   Naming context is read-only   at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.requireOwner(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:161)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.rebind(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:109)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.rebind(NamingContext.java:301)
>     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$3.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:335)
>     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:73)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 13:36:01,459 ERROR [org.jboss.as.naming] (pool-1-thread-2)
>   WFLYNAM0008: Unexpected internal error:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: WFLYNAM0043: Naming context
>   is read-only  at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.requireOwner(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:161)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.rebind(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:109)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.rebind(NamingContext.java:301)
>     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$3.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:335)
>     at
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:73)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 13:36:01,590 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb.client] (pool-1-thread-3) JBoss EJB
>   Client version 2.1.3.Final 13:36:01,918 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default -
>   1) log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (de.brockhaus.userMgmt.control.activity.StepOne).
>
> 13:36:01,920 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1) log4j:WARN Please
>   initialize the log4j system properly.
>
> 13:36:01,921 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1) log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: You cannot create EJB instances with `new`. The container creates them for you. Is `SomeProcess` really an EJB?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @SteveC. You are right. `SomeProcess` is only a java class.

Comment: Are you trying to do this within a single application or is your objective to share a single `SomeProcess` instance between applications?

Comment: I am doing this within a single application. My objective is running a Java Pattern called Resource Binder http://bit.ly/1MGobrJ.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern described in [HOW TO EXPOSE AND INJECT A POJO ...INTO AN EJB 3](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_expose_and_inject) works just fine in an unmodified WildFly server when you follow the recipe described. In particular, you should use:

```
@Resource(mappedName="SomeProcess")
private SomeProcess process;
```

rather than @Inject.

@Resource and @Inject are not interchangeable.

That said, this article is quite old in modern Java EE years and almost predates Java EE 6, where CDI was formally introduced.

Comment: Initially I have tried using @Resource annotation but I got errors too, so I changed and tried annotations with inject. The problem is that wildlfy server log works but the test java class with main method does not.

Comment: You should ask a different question regarding your testing issues